# How To call an Action after each changing in UITextField In Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, uitextfield

I have a searchbox in my app. It's class is UITextField Instead Of UISearchBar. I want to set up it to do as searchbar. For each string entered at time, do a (void)Search function with that string. But I don't know how to do that. In fact I want to call (void)Search after each character entered.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self Search];
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self Search];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use shouldChangeCharactersInRange to get current user input

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    NSString * searhQuery = [[textField text] stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

  [self Search:searhQuery];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: shokran seyedi.

Comment: @SaMiGiMiX kindly mark this answer as correct if it answers your question

Comment: @MohammadBashirSidani I did but at first 8 minutes system don't allow me do that.